# Deleting inherited types

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have 2 classes:

```
class A
{
public:
char * x;
char * y;
char * z;
A();
~A();
}

class B: public A
{
public:
char * o;
B();
~B();
}
```

I want to delete[] x, y, and z in class B's destructor (And yes, A's constructor does properly allocate x, y, and z). The code will compile fine, but upon execution it will crash. The properties are public, so inherited traits should be able to free up some memory for me, right?

Comment: Shouldn't you just delete them in class A's destructor, which will automatically be called when B's dtor is run?

Comment: Also, you should post the actual code of the ctors and dtors so people don't have to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Destructors are inherited? But constructors aren't?

Comment: If they are allocated in A's constructor, they should be deleted in A's destructor. Otherwise creating an instance of class A will always leak memory.

Comment: B's destructor will automatically call A's destructor. B's constructor must call an A constructor too. So in a sense both are 'inherited'.

Comment: @Saustin: it can be summarized like so: "Derived classes do not inherit or overload constructors or destructors from their base classes, but they do call the constructor and destructor of base classes." From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr374.htm

Comment: It was just a simple mis-understanding, I believe I have solved the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called A's constructor/destructor as well as B's, so that causes several issues on how I coded it, notably a severe memory leak. Thanks for all of the help guys, I just was confused due to someone telling me that onle constructors were inherited.

Comment: A couple of comments: you will want the dtor in `class A` to be virtual (unless you know for sure that you don't and can explain why). And the fact that constructors aren't inherited means, for example, that if `class A` had a constructor that took an int parameter, `A::A(int x);`, that `class B` would *not* have such a constructor unless it was also explicitly declared in `B`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual code, it may not be calling delete on `o`, and it may be double-deleting `x`, `y`, `z`.

You should correctly implement destruction in the base class (for base class members) and the derived class (for derived class members).  Let the trickle-down destructor behavior handle the base class destruction.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.12

> When I write a derived class's destructor, do I need to explicitly call the destructor for my base class?
>
> - No...
>     A derived class's destructor (whether or not you explicitly define one) automagically invokes the destructors for base class subobjects

Also, depending on how your code is used, you may also need to make your destructor virtual.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7

> When should my destructor be virtual?
>
> - When someone will delete a derived-class object via a base-class pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, whether it's a good idea is another question.

You say your code is crashing, but you've not given any evidence that it's because you are deleting A's mmeber variables in B's destructor. In fact if I had to guess I would say the cause of the cash is the lack of copy constructors and assignment operators in A and B (the so called 'rule of three', google it).

If your program is crashing then it's probably a good idea to post code that crashes. I think that would improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Don't forget the virtual destructor that he doesn't have that he needs to make this work. The destructor of `A` is declared without `virtual`. Also, he needs `A` to be an abstract class, so it can only be used with a derived class (that presumably destroys the stuff `A` creates).